# Fragments with recyclerView in ViewPager viewModels issue

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager2

I've got two `fragments` in viewpager and in every fragment is with seperated `recyclerViews`.

When I initialize seperated viewmodels like:

first fragment

```
    override val vm: NotesManagerViewModel by viewModels()
```

second fragment

```
    override val vm: SetGoalsViewModel by viewModels()
```

view pager

```
    override val vm: ViewPagerViewModel by viewModels()
```

I've got error:

```
 Process: com.example.learningmanager, PID: 10369
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.example.learningmanager.fragments.setgoals.ui.SetGoalsViewModel
```

When I use in my two fragments

```
by activityViewModels
```

to initialize vm's recyclerViews it doesn't crash, but adapters doesn't work properly it doesn't refresh well or doesn't load data at all.
I understand it is because it lives for activity scope and doesn't refresh data at all, doesn't create new viewmodel instance.
... but how to handle that kind of implementation to refresh my viewmodels, data every time I need it i.e. after adding new element to database and in adapter.

Full error stacktrace:

```
W/System: A resource failed to call release. 
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.learningmanager, PID: 10369
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.example.learningmanager.fragments.setgoals.ui.SetGoalsViewModel
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:221)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:278)
        at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateViewModelFactory.create(SavedStateViewModelFactory.java:112)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:185)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:150)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy.getValue(ViewModelProvider.kt:54)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy.getValue(ViewModelProvider.kt:41)
        at com.example.learningmanager.fragments.setgoals.ui.SetGoalsFragment.getVm(SetGoalsFragment.kt:21)
        at com.example.learningmanager.fragments.setgoals.ui.SetGoalsFragment.getVm(SetGoalsFragment.kt:18)
        at com.example.learningmanager.base.ui.BaseFragment.collectNavigationEvents(BaseFragment.kt:42)
        at com.example.learningmanager.base.ui.BaseFragment.onViewCreated(BaseFragment.kt:36)
        at com.example.learningmanager.fragments.setgoals.ui.SetGoalsFragment.onViewCreated(SetGoalsFragment.kt:25)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:3019)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:551)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:261)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1840)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1758)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1670)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitNow(BackStackRecord.java:317)
        at androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter.placeFragmentInViewHolder(FragmentStateAdapter.java:341)
        at androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter.onViewAttachedToWindow(FragmentStateAdapter.java:276)
        at androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter.onViewAttachedToWindow(FragmentStateAdapter.java:67)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchChildAttached(RecyclerView.java:7556)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$5.addView(RecyclerView.java:860)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.ChildHelper.addView(ChildHelper.java:107)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.addViewInt(RecyclerView.java:8601)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.addView(RecyclerView.java:8559)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.addView(RecyclerView.java:8547)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1641)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1587)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.scrollBy(LinearLayoutManager.java:1391)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.scrollHorizontallyBy(LinearLayoutManager.java:1116)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.scrollStep(RecyclerView.java:1838)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$SmoothScroller.onAnimation(RecyclerView.java:11920)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$ViewFlinger.run(RecyclerView.java:5390)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:972)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:796)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:727)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:957)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.example.learningmanager.fragments.setgoals.ui.SetGoalsViewModel> has no zero argument constructor
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:219)
            ... 45 more
```

EDIT:

viewmodel second

```
@HiltViewModel
class SetGoalsViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val getGoalsItemDetailsUseCase: GetGoalsItemDetailsUseCase
) : BaseViewModel() {
    val setGoalsData = MutableStateFlow<List<SetGoalsData>>(emptyList())

    init {
        getActualState()
    }

    private fun getActualState() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            getGoalsItemDetailsUseCase.build(Unit).collect {
                setGoalsData.value = it
            }
        }
    }

    fun onNavigateToSave() {
        navigateTo(SetGoalsToSaveScreenKey())
    }

    fun deleteItem(id: Int) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            //usecase with id
            getActualState()
        }
    }

    fun onItemClicked(id: Int) {
        // navigaton to root
    }
}
```

viewmodel first

```
@HiltViewModel
class NotesManagerViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val application: Application,
    private val addNotesItemsUseCase: AddNotesItemsUseCase,
    private val deleteNotesItemsUseCase: DeleteNotesItemsUseCase,
    private val getNotesItemsUseCase: GetNotesItemsUseCase,
    private val searchNotesItemUseCase: SearchNotesItemUseCase,
    private val updateNotesItemsUseCase: UpdateNotesItemsUseCase
) : BaseViewModel() {
    val noteDataList = MutableStateFlow<List<NoteData>>(emptyList())
    val searchDataList = MutableStateFlow<List<NoteData>>(emptyList())

    init {
        getActualState()
    }
    fun getActualState() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            getNotesItemsUseCase.build(Unit).collect {
                noteDataList.value = it
                Log.d("newNoteData", "${noteDataList.value}")
            }
        }
    }

    fun updateNote(existingNoteData: NoteData) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            updateNotesItemsUseCase.create(existingNoteData)
            getActualState()
        }
    }

    fun deleteNote(existingNoteData: NoteData) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            deleteNotesItemsUseCase.create(existingNoteData)
            getActualState()
        }
    }
    fun saveNote(newNoteData: NoteDataDetailsResponse) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            addNotesItemsUseCase.create(newNoteData)
            Log.d("newNoteData", "$newNoteData")
        }
    }

    fun searchNote(query: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            searchNotesItemUseCase.create(query).collectLatest {
                searchDataList.value = it
                Log.d("FromVM", "${searchDataList.value}")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include the entire stacktrace

Comment: it's done you wanted full error?

Comment: I think your's secondviewmodel class is not properly init,  Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.example.learningmanager.fragments.setgoals.ui.SetGoalsViewModel> has no zero argument constructor

Comment: but it is not wrong, the same as in first viewmodel I edited my main post to put it. 
I think it is because first vm is initialized in viewpager normally, but second is with error because it wants to override scope which gives error. It overrides vm in the same viewpager which is impossible and gives error.
Fragments in viewpager has to have the same initialization once generated and how to workaround to achieve another initialization? I dont know it

Comment: In brief,
viewpager doesn't allow to reinitialize viewmodels inside it, recycler wants to reinitialize it and I use many viewmodels not only one for every fragment in viewpager. When I worked with viewpager with onboarding case I have one viewmodel for different fragments and it's ok, but I do not know how to achieve it here. 
Create one viewmodel for every fragment which is in Viewpager? for me it doesn't seem ok, but could work, but... it will refresh every fragment in viewpager when I add element just to one I do not see it like proper implementation but could work.